# Can I buy real estate in the US and get a visa?

Tags: usa, visa, resident-permit, real-estate

I have no US visa and have never been to the USA, but I want to buy real estate and emmigrate there.

I would like to know what process I need to obtain residency in the USA. If I acquire real estate in the USA, will that help me with process?

Comment: I do not know of any way to use real estate. If you can invest at least $500,000 in a new business in a targeted employment area, or $1 million outside a targeted area, you could get an [EB-5](https://www.uscis.gov/greencard/investors) green card.